# Logica de condiciones en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda respecto a la lógica en las condiciones de C++. tengo el diguiente código:

```
if (distanciaCM<=50 && digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH || f=="off"){
//mi código si se cumple la condición
}
```

Ahora, ¿estoy en lo correcto si digo que el código dentro de la condición se cumplirá si ambas condiciones, la primera y segunda se cumplen o si la tercera se cumple? Osea, ¿el código se ejecutará en cualquiera de los 2 casos? ¡O son 3 o sólo uno?

Comment: Sólo agregar que && se evalúa antes que || (mayor orden de precedencia), pero ante la duda, es una práctica común poner paréntesis adicionales, que pueden ayudar a aclarar la idea y no dañan, con lo que la expresión podría quedar: `if ((distanciaCM<=50 && digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH) || f=="off")`, que dice lo mismo y puede evitar malos entendidos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes traducir

```
distanciaCM<=50 && digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH || f=="off"
```

Como una **tabla de verdad**

**A** = distanciaCM<=50

**B** = digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH

**C** = f=="off"

Si haces dicha tabla, esta serían las "posibilidades" en las combinaciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejor respuesta de la que esperaba, gracias!!!

Answer (score 4):

Como añadido a las excelentes respuestas de [Reynald0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132852/2742) y [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132865/2742) me gustaría comentar algo que se les ha pasado por alto a ambos y que es relevante en tu pregunta.

#### Pregunta.

> ¿Estoy en lo correcto si digo que el código dentro de la condición se cumplirá si ambas condiciones, la primera y segunda se cumplen o si la tercera se cumple?

En Español, tu código dice lo siguiente:

```
if (distanciaCM<=50 && digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH || f=="off"){
//mi código si se cumple la condición
}
```

> *Si `distanciaCM` es menor o igual a `50` **Y** el retorno de `digitalRead(bombaPIN)` es `HIGH`, **O** si `f` es `"off"` entonces ejecuta el código*.

#### Lógica perezosa.

Pero en C++ la frase del apartado anterior no es exactamente cierta; C++ usa [evaluación de cortocircuito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_de_cortocircuito)<sup>1</sup> lo que significa que si tras evaluar el primer operando de una sentencia lógica podemos ignorar el segundo operando, este segundo operando no será ejecutado.

#### ¿En qué casos C++ cortocircuita la evaluación?

- Al evaluar `A && B` si `A` es `false`, sabemos que toda la operación será `false` con independencia del valor de `B` así pues, `B` no se evalúa.
- Al evaluar `A || B` si `A` es `true`, sabemos que toda la operación será `true` con independencia del valor de `B` así pues, `B` no se evalúa.

#### Consecuencias para el código.

Si alguno de los operandos cortocircuitados es una llamada a función esa función no será llamada. En tu caso tienes una llamada a función en el lado del cortocircuito (`digitalRead(bombaPIN)`) y esa llamada no se producirá si `distanciaCM` es menor o igual a `50`, por otro lado la comparación `f=="off"` tampoco se producirá nunca si `distanciaCM` es menor o igual a `50` y el retorno de `digitalRead(bombaPIN)` es `HIGH`, podemos comprobarlo con este código:

```
enum e { HIGH, LOW };

bool digitalRead(bool b) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return b ? HIGH : LOW;
}

struct F {
    bool operator ==(const char *tag) const {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        return false;
    };
} f;

int main()
{
    for (int distanciaCM = 45; distanciaCM != 55; ++distanciaCM)
    {
        const bool bombaPIN = (distanciaCM % 2) == 0;

        std::cout << distanciaCM << '\n';
        if (distanciaCM<=50 && digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH || f=="off"){
            std::cout << "mi código si se cumple la condición\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior vemos como la función `digitalRead` tiene como efecto secundario mostrar su nombre en la consola; también vemos que hace lo mismo la llamada al operador de equidad del objeto `F`, esto produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 45
> digitalRead
> operator==
> 46
> digitalRead
> mi código si se cumple la condición
> 47
> digitalRead
> operator==
> 48
> digitalRead
> mi código si se cumple la condición
> 49
> digitalRead
> operator==
> 50
> digitalRead
> mi código si se cumple la condición
> 51
> operator==
> 52
> operator==
> 53
> operator==
> 54
> operator==
> ```

Podemos ver que mientras `distanciaCM` es menor o igual a `50` la función `digitalRead` se ha ejecutado (se ha cortocircuitado). También podemos ver que cuando la primera parte de la expresión era verdadera la segunda parte tampoco se ha ejecutado:

```
| distanciaCM | distanciaCM<=50 | digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH |         f=="off" |
|          45 |       verdadero |                         falso |            falso |
|          46 |       verdadero |                     verdadero |    cortocircuito |
|          47 |       verdadero |                         falso |            falso |
|          48 |       verdadero |                     verdadero |    cortocircuito |
|          49 |       verdadero |                         falso |            falso |
|          50 |       verdadero |                     verdadero |    cortocircuito |
|          51 |           falso |                 cortocircuito |            falso |
|          52 |           falso |                 cortocircuito |            falso |
|          53 |           falso |                 cortocircuito |            falso |
|          54 |           falso |                 cortocircuito |            falso |
```

Como ves, siempre que `distanciaCM<=50` no se cumplía, la función `digitalRead` no era ejecutada, también podemos ver que si `distanciaCM<=50 && digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH` era verdadero, no se llamaba la segunda parte de la comparación.

#### Reordenar condiciones.

Si necesitases que la función `digitalRead` fuese llamada siempre deberás darle la vuelta a la expresión:

```
//  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- siempre se ejecuta
if (digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH && distanciaCM<=50 || f=="off"){
//        posible cortocircuito ---> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//mi código si se cumple la condición
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Los operadores definidos por el usuario (OdU) no se ven afectados por el cortocircuito.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como lógica perezosa.

Answer (score 3):

Como no hay paréntesis que agrupen las expresiones entonces los operadores se irán evaluando según dicte su orden de precedencia.

El operador `&&` tiene mas prioridad que el operador `||` luego se evaluará en primera instancia. Así,  la siguiente expresión sería equivalente:

```
if ((distanciaCM<=50 && digitalRead(bombaPIN) == HIGH) || f=="off")
//  ^                                                ^
```

O, simplificando:

```
if ((A && B) || C)
```

La tabla de verdad es la que te ha comentado [@Reynald0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132852/463), por lo que no veo necesidad de repetirla.